# "none like him" vs "none like unto him"

Tags: word-usage

Are "there is none like Him" and "there is none like unto Him" exactly synonymous, or is there a nuance between the two ? (the second construct is often used to translate certain Muslim idioms).

Comment: I should imagine the only reason you might see ***unto*** more often in certain translated Muslim idioms is because it's archaic, so if it's used at all in a more modern context, there's probably an element of allusion to *old, long-established traditions, sacred texts, etc*.

Comment: "Muslim idioms" or "Arabic idioms" ?

Comment: Isn't the second form also used in some Bible translations?

Comment: Honestly, I'm confused by what "unto" is supposed to mean here.  As far as I can find, "unto" mean "to", "by", or "until", which doesn't make a whole lot of sense.  "none like to Him"? "none like by Him"? "none like until Him"?

Comment: In the seventeenth century _like unto_ was a compound preposition, equivalent to modern _like_.

Comment: @ColinFine Thank you for this clarification, I think you should include it in your answer since my question was primarily about meaning

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Like unto* is wholly archaic in modern English, used in the King James Bible (1611) and other texts that are either of that era, or wishing to emulate the language of that era.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen these terms used in modern scriptures as well - the Book of Mormon, the Pearl of Great Price, etc. In these contexts the use of “like” seems to connote “similar”, whereas the term “like unto” seems to mean “the same as or identical”. That nuance can be very important.

Comment: King James Bible: *"the kingdom of heaven is like unto a net, that was cast into the sea, and gathered of every kind: Which, when it was full, they drew to shore, and sat down, and gathered the good into vessels, but cast the bad away."*  So certainly, *"like unto"* did not mean *"the same as"* in the 17th century (unless you think Heaven is a fishing net).